# Export exceeding limits

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, export

I have generated the map in google earth engine and QGIS. For example the 2019 NO2 levels for South Africa. I then filtered the layer for SA using a SA shapefile. I then try to export the layer. It then gives me Request payload size exceeds the limit: 4194304 bytes.

```
var band = NO2.select('NO2_column_number_density');
var banddate = band.filterDate('2019-04-01', '2019-04-30');
var median = banddate.median();
var SA = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('locname', 'South Africa'));
var banddateSA = median.clipToCollection(SA);

var spectral = (['#a50026','#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61','#fee08b','#ffffbf','#d9ef8b','#a6d96a','#66bd63','#1a9850','#006837']);

Map.setCenter(24.52, -28.77, 5);
Map.addLayer(banddateSA, {min: 0.0, max:0.0002, palette: spectral.reverse(Display)}, 'NO2');
Map.addLayer(SA, {color: 'yellow'});

Export.image.toDrive({
image: banddateSA,
description: "NO2",
fileNamePrefix: "NO2",
region: table,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1000000000000000,
fileDimensions: 10,
fileFormat: "GeoTIFF",
});
```

Comment: You haven't provided a complete running script, so it's hard to help you. I'm guessing it might be your geometry being too complex. Try to simplify it and run again.

Comment: Probably, changing `region: table` to `region: SA.bounds()` fixes the (possibly) complex geometry